# What exactly is the difference between RA, SHRA and TSRA in METAR and TAF reports?

Tags: weather, metar, taf

What exactly is the difference between RA, SHRA and TSRA in METAR and TAF reports? I couldn't find a source where they were all compared together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:

- `RA`: Moderate rain
- `TSRA`: Thunderstorm with rain
- `SHRA`: Shower(s) of rain

How this is constructed is detailed below.

---

From [WMO Aerodrome Reports and Forecasts](https://library.wmo.int/viewer/30224?medianame=782_2022_edition_en_#page=1&viewer=picture&o=bookmark&n=0&q=), abbreviations for precipitations are:

[image]

A type of precipitation is `RA` for rain. It can be associated with a one or more qualifiers, e.g. `TS` for thunderstorm, `SH` for shower, `+` for heavy, etc. No qualifier means moderate.

**Definitions**

- Thunderstorms: One or more sudden electrical discharges, manifested by a flash of light (lightning) and a sharp or rumbling sound (thunder). Thunderstorms are associated with convective clouds (cumulonimbus) and are usually accompanied by precipitation. The associated cumulonimbus has vertical updraughts that may reach 30 m/s in the more vigorous cells. Downdraughts also occur,
  especially in the later stages of development, with speeds of about half of those for updraughts.
- Showers: Precipitation, often short-lived and heavy, falling from convective clouds. A shower is characterized by the suddenness with which it starts and stops, and generally by large and rapid changes in precipitation intensity.

**Use**

- The qualifier `TS` shall be used whenever thunder is heard or lightning detected at the aerodrome within the 10-min period preceding the observation.
- When an automatic observing system is used and when showers (`SH`) cannot be determined with a method that takes account of the presence of convective cloud, the precipitation should not be characterized by `SH`.
- The descriptor `SH` (showers) cannot be associated with ice pellets (PL).

**Examples**

- `RA`: (Moderate) rain
- `+SHRA`: Heavy showers of rain
- `TSRA`: Thunderstorm with rain

Comment: Note that `TS` can be used with other precip, for example `TSSN`, or with no precip, as `VC TS`. Note also that the intensity modifier applies to the precip, so `+TSRA` means "thunderstorm with heavy rain" and NOT "heavy thunderstorm with rain."

Comment: @randomhead: One or two qualifiers can be used with any single weather phenomenon (`SH`, `+`, ... are qualifiers, not weather phenomena). Generally, qualifiers cannot be used alone, but `TS` is an exception, it is both a qualifier and a phenomenon (though this is not visible in the table).

Answer (score 2):

TS stands for thunderstorms, so TSRA means rain associated with thunderstorms.

RA means steady and continuous rain. SHRA means rain showers. Showers stop and start abruptly and can vary in intensity.